# Cálculo del promedio por columnas y filas y desviación Power BI

Tags: matriz, powerbi

Os comento, tengo una tabla con una serie de movimientos listados con fecha y usuario.

Necesitaría realizar mediante el BI la siguiente visualización, donde por una parte aparezca la suma de veces que cada usuario hizo ese movimiento en ese día, y luego los promedios de filas y columnas. También me gustaría sacar el % de cada fila (y columna) respecto al promedio de filas y columnas.

No sé muy bien como realizarlo en Power BI, y si la misma situación me serviría luego para visualizarlo y manipularlo en Excel.

Gracias de antemano!

|  | Día 1 | Día 2 | Día 3 | Día 4 | Promedio Usuario | % respecto al promedio de los usuarios |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Usuario 1 | 30 | 82 | 33 | 77 |  |  |
| Usuario 2 | 17 | 94 | 54 | 33 |  |  |
| Promedio diario |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| % respecto al promedio de los días |  |  |  |  |  |  |